# VS Code extension coderunner not working properly on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am new to programming and wanted to setup c++ on my MacBook Air M1 running on macOS Monterey. I followed some online tutorials to download Homebrew, Mingw-64(using Homebrew) and finally installed VS Code and then installed the c++ extension pack and code-runner extension.

However when I tried to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "helloworld" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: MinGW is an abbreviation for "Minimal GCC for **Windows**". That doesn't seem like the correct choice for macOS development.

Comment: Well, may you please suggest some solution as I am a complete newbie in this field.

Comment: How about [using Clang in VSCode on macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)?